# A Better Django Admin ManyToMany Field Widget

Tags: javascript, django, django-admin, html-select

I find the the Django Admin's default `models.ManyToManyField` widget to be cumbersome to use. It's the [HTML select](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_SELECT_MULTIPLE.html) element and if you have a lot of Objects of the "other" model then it's quite impractical to actually find the "other" Objects you want to associate with "this" Object. And if you have ***a lot*** of objects of the "other" model it seems to even slows down the rendering of the Admin page.

I'm aware that I can build my own custom admin widget and apply it to my `ManyToManyFields` as I see fit, but are there any pre-built ones out there that I might use instead? In my dreams, I picture an auto-completing text input HTML widget. Is this even practical/possible to do in the Django admin framework?

Thanks.

Answer (score 198, accepted):

Try using the `filter_horizontal` attribute on your admin class, for example:

```
class SomeModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    filter_horizontal = ('users',)
```

As mentioned in [the documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.filter_horizontal), "adding a ManyToManyField to this list will instead use a nifty unobtrusive JavaScript "filter" interface that allows searching within the options". [`filter_vertical`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.filter_vertical) does the same thing with a slightly different layout.

Comment: Its Working But how to make this filed read only. I am try 
read only_fields = ('users',) . But Its shown in single line separated by comma. I want to shown in line break ...

Answer (score 7):

you could try using a raw id in the admin. 
and the django docs:
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields

if you are looking for something with auto-complete you might want to look at this as a starting point http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/AutoCompleteSolutions

and finally a very simplistic inline Example:

models.py

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToMany(User)
```

admin.py:

```
class SomeModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    raw_id_fields = ("users",)
```

Comment: This only allows to select _one_ user though, not multiple.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't actually played with it but I found [this promising looking library](https://github.com/crucialfelix/django-ajax-selects) referenced elsewhere.

It appears to do exactly what I wanted.  Rather than loading the entire list of related objects (regardless of how many there are!) and presenting you with a picker to select a few of them, as `filter_horizontal` does, it presents a search/filter box and uses typeahead/autocomplete calls to retrieve results dynamically.  This is great for the case where you have maybe 5000 users and want to pick 3 or 4 of them without waiting for 5k `<option>` elements to download and render.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using Inline model as such -

```
class ManyToManyInline(TabularInline): 
    model = MyModel.many_to_many_field_name.through 
    raw_id_fields = ("render_raw_id_using_this",) 

@register(MyModel) 
class YourAdminClass(AnyBaseClass): 
    exclude = ("many_to_many_field_name",) 
    inlines = (ManyToManyInline,)
```

Now there is another issue I faced, finding "render_raw_id_using_this" field name.

So, I moved to shell and tried finding fields in through model as such -

```
In [1]: MyModel.many_to_many_field_name.through._meta.fields 
Out [1]: (<django.db.models.fields.AutoField: id>, <django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey: fieldname1>, <django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey: fieldname2>)
```

So, I replaced `render_raw_id_using_this` with `fieldname1`

Similarly, you can use these field names to render raw id instead of drop down list in Inline model.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I want to add an answer here for people who find this just like I did: this situation is exactly what Django inline admins are for.  Specifically, I use TabularInlines with raw id fields for many-to-many relations that have too many choices.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.TabularInline